# importing numpy from different directory

Tags: python, numpy

I have numpy folder placed in abc and added it to path

```
>>> from abc import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ahsin\Desktop\naresh\abc\numpy\__init__.py", line 166, in <module>
    core.getlimits._register_known_types()
  File "C:\Users\ahsin\Desktop\naresh\abc\numpy\core\getlimits.py", line 109, in _register_known_types
    eps=exp2(f16(-10)),
TypeError: can only be called with ndarray object
```

I tried replicating issue in python prompt and could observe this

```
>>> exp2(f16(-10))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only be called with ndarray object


>>> f16(-10)
-10.0


>>> exp2(-10.0)
0.0009765625
```

Can anyone help please

Answer (score 0):

Little wrong question I think - not "importing numpy from different directory" but "problem with importing numpy from non-standard package".

It not works because you use patch/tricks - that is wrong idea in programs :)

Do this in normal way - set correct path and import:

```
# change path before import
saved_path = sys.path
sys.path = ['abc']

import numpy
# restore path
sys.path = saved_path
```

You fault is that you changing module name and dependency in this module can not be imported I think but I am not sure.